# Windows Phone 7 AdControl too wide for screen

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm using a 480x80 AdControl in a WP7.1 app, and it seems to be one pixel too wide to fit on the screen.  Here's (a subset of) the XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <!-- ... -->
        <adctl:AdControl  Width="480" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,633,0,0" Name="adControl" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And here's what it looks like (in the emulator):

[image: Off by one]

If I move it to the left by one pixel in the XAML, the border gets chopped off on the left side instead of the right side.  I'm a WP7 newbie, but the border thickness are all 0s, and other properties look ok?

I can't believe this is how the ads are supposed to be -- do I need to use a smaller ad, or is there some way I can shrink the border here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're inside a pivot control, I think the default pivot control gives a 12 margin.  You have to use a negative margin to overcome that.  What I do instead is put the pivot control in a grid control, and have two rows, both with Height set to Auto, and put the ad control into one and the pivot into the other.  If there is no ad available, the pivot control will take up the entire space.  If there is an ad, it fits properly.

[Edit]
Also, ensure that the emulator is zoomed to 100% when looking at this.  ;)

Comment: Or, generally in the content panel of any of the default controls.  Panorama is even more evident, because the content panel is even narrower to allow for the next panorama item to be visible on the right side.

Comment: Thanks Rich.  This got me exploring in the right area.  It turns out that the emulator was zoomed out at 66%, unbeknownst to me.  (Doh!)  After zooming to 100% the border looks correct, so it was fine all along.  It must have been an artifact of multiplying 480 pixels by 2/3rds and getting a result one pixel too wide to fit.

Comment: (BTW: if you want to add a second answer of "make sure the emulator is at 100% zoom", I'll change it to be the accepted one.  Though this answer is likely to be useful to more people going forward.)

Comment: Mike, I edited the original answer to include zooming the emulator to 100%.  ;)